# CSS and JS bundle not found in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bundle

When I publish or run application on local machine with Release mode bundles not working properly. It generates URL something like this:

```
http://localhost:60676/Content/css/?v=rRDBls2mnY7IG-YV_CwsQLv__74wfMTc-gyS9foHN601
http://localhost:60676/bundles/jquery?v=FVs3ACwOLIVInrAl5sdzR2jrCDmVOWFbZMY6g6Q0ulE1
http://localhost:60676/bundles/jqueryval?v=0EJjPUV3D0sQSPyawK-IAWWKeZ8W_Vg3wDTJ1MI1v3M1
http://localhost:60676/bundles/modernizr?v=wBEWDufH_8Md-Pbioxomt90vm6tJN2Pyy9u9zHtWsPo1
```

In console error read like this:
*

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)

My code in Global.asax is as per below in `Application_Start()`

`BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
 BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;`

Answer (score 3):

This error mostly occurs due to a collisions between bundle urls and a physical files/folders.

For example if your solution has a following structure:

```
   -root
     -bundles
        -jquery.js
```

And you define a bundle like this:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/bundles/jquery-{version}.js"));
```

This will result in 403

So what you need to do, is to ensure that bundle urls have no corresponding folders in your solution.

Comment: Well the default in a MVC5 template contains a bundle in the "~/Content/css" folder, so by default the template is wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue except I was getting a 500 error.

I did the following:

1. Make sure that you do not have a separate script block or any references to Session outside of scripting in your _Layout.cshtml page

   - place any script blocks inside the head section after the Scripts.Render calls
   - do not do this, (I think this may be where it was complaining about referencing session - not sure):

     @Html.Hidden("TimeOutSetting", Session.Timeout)

then reference it in the script block outside of the head section

```
    $("#TimeOutSetting").val()

- instead use this in the scripting:

    @Session.Timeout
```

2. Make sure all script blocks are surrounded by @section Scripts {} on
   all the other pages
3. in the RegisterBundles function add this so it compiles correctly
   depending on whether you've selected Debug or Release

   ```
   #if DEBUG
           BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false;
   #else
           BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
   #endif
   ```
4. And lastly I had some debug code that I had added to the Global.asx.cs file and I think it was complaining about referencing Session here. This may not be the case, but I removed it & it worked...

   ```
   protected void Application_AcquireRequestState(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
       var session = context.Session;
       var newSession = session.IsNewSession;
       var cookieLess = session.IsCookieless;
       var sessionId = session.SessionID;
       string sessionCookie = context.Request.Headers["Cookie"];
   }
   ```

I hope this helps prevent you from going insane as I almost did before I finally figured this one out.

Good luck!